# Nginx limit_req not working for HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, https, fail2ban

I have the following in my config to redirect http traffic to https:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    limit_req zone=one burst=100;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
         }
```

In my https server block I have

```
 server {
      listen  443;
      limit_req zone=one burst=100;
----MORE CONFIGS HERE-----
         }
```

When I run a test to see if the limit_req is working I run the following:

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 https://myurlhere.com
```

The limit_req works perfect.

However when I run

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://myurlhere.com
```

limit_req does not catch for http to https redirect. Any ideas why?

Comment: The directive is meant to work under the server context. I wonder if the rate limiting doesn't apply to 3xx response codes. Can you change your configuration to test this hypothesis? Add a location / and give it a root, test, then change location to include a redirect instead?

Comment: I believe you are correct. With location / it registers limit_req however with the 301 redirect inside location it does not. Any way to bypass this limitation?

Comment: Possibly change the source code. I'll convert my comment into an answer, which you can accept if you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My theory, which you confirmed, is that the rate limiting does not apply to 3xx status codes. It may only apply to 200 status codes.

Looking at the source code may be one way to determine this, though I had a quick look at the module source and nothing stood out. It may be that the module is only called with specific response codes, I'm not familiar enough with Nginx source to work it out quickly.

Comment: `rewrite` module directives are executed before `limit_req` and `return` just stops proceeding a request and response immediately. So nginx never has a chance to check limits

Comment: See http://www.nginxguts.com/2011/01/phases/